# VsCode: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5678 when trying to debuging blender with VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, blender, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to remote debug Blender with VsCode.

I found this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVDf2VSmRvk

Where he used a blender addon to connect to remote connect to VsCode. These all worked, But when I went into  VsCode, and try to run the debugging, it gave me this error message:

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5678
```

Blender is still waiting for connection when I got this message.
I really don't know how to solve this, can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Also, this is my lauch.json file:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Attach",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 5678, //careful, this used to be 3000 in older versions of vscode and this addon
      "host": "localhost"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is my system info:

OS: Mac Big Sur

blender-debugger-for-vscode Add-on Version: 2.0.0

Blender Version: 2.90.0

VS Code Version: 1.67.2

VS Code Python Extension Version: 2022.6.2

debugpy version: 1.6.0

Paths listed by where python or the corresponding command:
/Users/lhwang/.pyenv/shims/python

Does VS Code / Visual Studio connect to the troubleshooting script?
No. It shows its waiting for connection

Python path/interpreter detected/selected by VS Code/Visual Studio:
/Users/lhwang/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/bin/python3.7